# CKEditor: Show partial blog before login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I am using the [CKEditor gem](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) to maintain a blog. I want individuals to login to the system before they can read the entire blog post. They will be shown a preview of the blog post with a *Login to read more* button if they are not logged in.

For other parts of the website, I can use [truncate](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate) or similar calls to show part of the content. However, as the table stores the entire html in the table, truncate will not work here. Looking for tips on how to accomplish the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it was pretty simple. Posting the answer here for anyone else who might have struggled with this.

`truncate(strip_tags(blog.details), :length => 300, :omission =>'', :escape => false`

`strip_tags` does the trick and you can use additional arguments for truncation and include it in an `if else` block to control view.